# Entry in /etc/host file not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hosts

I am facing an issue  when I make the 
entry

```
192.168.32.56 example.org
```

in /etc/hosts file 
 ,it does not work. But when I remove it , it starts working. Below is my /etc/hosts file for Ubuntu 16 . I also changed the permissions of hosts file to 777, then also its not working. A few days back it was working but it stopped now.

```
# BEGIN hosts added by Network Connect
192.0.47.198  access-dc.example.org
# END hosts added by Network Connect
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       icanw42slpc2666

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

# LA 
192.168.32.56  example.org

# DC
#192.168.47.56  example.org
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: when I do ping example.org it does not respond. Also when I go to browser and then type http://example.org , the page does not come up.

Comment: Does `ping 192.168.32.56` work?

Comment: PING example.org (192.168.32.56) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- example.icann.org ping statistics ---
253 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 258046ms

Comment: So the hosts entry is working (see it says `example.org (192.168.32.56)`). If the host on that IP doesn't respond, adding entries to `/etc/hosts` isn't going to change anything.

Comment: ping 192.168.32.56 does not work.

Comment: Yes, that’s what we’re saying: since you can’t reach the host, nothing in `/etc/hosts` can help you. Since `example.org` *is* being resolved to 192.168.32.56, the entry in `/etc/hosts` itself *is* working — the only purpose of `/etc/hosts` is to provide name resolution. Network connectivity is another problem.

Comment: people on windows are able to do it.. why not from linux? Also it was working before some time for me as well on linux

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Linux or Windows. A windows system can't ping an address it can't reach either.

Comment: Put the permissions of the file back to the correct value

Answer (score 1):

All of you are absolutely correct. The ip of the server was changed. After updating the new IP , I am able to ping and connect by browser. Thank you so much .